# How to calulate the total up to the current row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have an excel spreadsheet, I want to change the value in a column based on a threshold. Basically if a certain column up to that row is less than 5000 I want the value to be 70, if its over I want it to be 80. Here is my current formula

```
=IF(SUM([TOTAL]) >= 5000, 80, 70)
```

I tried using `ROW()` within the `SUM()` function but its not accepting it. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** This is also in a table

Comment: You're using a table based on your formula, so that total will include rows below. If you're not messing with the sorting you could right the formula by only locking the top bound. `=if(sum( $A$2:$A2)>=5000, 80,70)` and drag the formula down accordingly and adjust the sum range accordingly. This is written for context in the second row.

Comment: For `Structured References` aka tables running total to check if it based on threshold  `=IF(SUM(INDEX([TOTAL],1):[@TOTAL])>=5000,80,70)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya That worked perfectly thank you, would you like to possibly write it in a full answer with bit of an explanation and I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Alright. will do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Using `SUM()` function this should work, however, when working with **`Structured Tables`** one needs to use the following with `INDEX()` function to get the **Running/Rolling** sum.*

[image]

---

```
=IF(SUM(INDEX([TOTAL],1):[@TOTAL])>=5000,80,70)
```

---

- To explain, the formula logic is simple, it uses `=SUM(First:TillCurrentRow)`. Where `First` is the first row in the `[TOTAL]` Column while `TillCurrentRow` is the reference to the cell in the current row of the `[TOTAL]` Column.
- Therefore, to get the reference of the first cell, we need to use a function like `INDEX()` . `INDEX([TOTAL],1)` this dont returns the actual value instead returns a reference to the first cell in the `[TOTAL]` column while in order to get the reference to the current row we simply use `[@TOTAL]` which is the usual syntax to get the present row when using `Structured References` aka `Tables.

[image]

- Lastly, using `SUM()` function to get the sum of the rows and then wrapping with in an `IF()` function to do logic calculations.

---